# Как получить value в input используя Zend\Dom\Query

Tags: php, zend-framework

Пытаюсь получить значение input в следующем коде.

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="cOpkqickNLImH72xbqz" />
```

Делаю следующим образом

```
use Zend\Dom\Query;

$dom = new Query($html); // В $html содержится html-файл, с кодом указанным выше
$results = $dom->execute('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]');

$count = count($results); // Значение $count равно 1, значит элемент находится успешно
echo $results->current()->nodeName; // Выводит 'input' - тоже верно
echo $results->current()->nodeValue; // Выводит пустое значение. Почему?

// Проверим регулярокой
preg_match('/name="__RequestVerificationToken".+?value="([^"]+)"/', $html, $match);
echo $match[1];// Выводит cOpkqickNLImH72xbqz
```

Как правильно получить значение value в input средствами Zend\Dom\Query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено. Кому будет интересно:

```
if($results->count()) {
    $value = $results->current()->getAttribute('value');
}
```